# FullColumnSelect not working in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Actually i'm trying to hightlight whole the column when a user click on a cell of the DataGridView.

The source is load dynamically from the user so initially DataGridView is null.

The issue is that if i change SelectionMode to FullColumnSelect or anyother SelectionMode options nothing change, the DataGridView will still have the SelectionMode as FullRowSelect even if i change it programmatically.

How can i solve that problem and hightlight entire column on user click?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i had to set `SortMode` to `NotSortable` for each column of the `DataGrid` but only after i've called `.DataSource`

So the code is the following

```
            Grid.DataSource = dt

            For Each c In Grid.Columns
                c.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            Next
            Grid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect
```